# Función pivot() versus get_dummies()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Puedo conseguir una tabla con la media anual de las cotizaciones incluidas en una base de datos, de la siguiente manera.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr 

datos = pdr.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', "2000-1-4", "2020-12-30")
# Media de las cotizaciones de cada año.
media_anual = datos["Close"].resample("Y").mean().reset_index()
tabla = media_anual.pivot ( columns='Date', values="Close")
tabla[:3]
```

La salida es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizando la función get_dummies, puedo mejorar la presentación de ésta tabla

```
pd.get_dummies(media_anual, columns=['Date'])
```

me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es, ¿Se pueden conseguir las fechas de la tabla devuelta por get_dummies, con el mismo formato que ls devueltas por el primer script?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he resuelto convirtiendo la columna **datetime64** a **string**, de la siguiente manera

```
from datetime import datetime

fechas = media_anual["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
media_anual["Fechas"] = fechas
media_anual.drop(["Date" ], axis = 'columns', inplace=True)
media_anual = media_anual[["Fechas", "Close"]]
pd.get_dummies(media_anual, columns=['Fechas'])[:3]
```